# Struts tags not working on default action

Tags: jsp, struts2, localization, tags

I have this **struts.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="com.alexsimo.examen6" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <default-action-ref name="login-form" />

        <action name="login-form">
            <result>login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="login" class="com.alexsimo.examen6.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">home.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="logout" class="com.alexsimo.examen6.LoginAction" method="logout">
            <result>login.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

I want to achieve the normal login flow. The user enter website's root and it gets the "login form", he submits, validation is made (this case i have a **LoginAction-validation.xml** file, name exactly as login action name) and then the user is sent to home page, in this case home.jps.

The content of login.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link href="<s:url value="/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title><s:property value="%{getText('login.title')}" /></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="languages">
        <s:url action="login" id="urlIdiomaES">
            <s:param name="request_locale">es</s:param>
        </s:url>
        <s:url action="login" id="urlIdiomaEN">
            <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
        </s:url>
        <ul>
            <li><s:a href="%{getText('urlIdiomaES')}">Español</s:a></li>
            <li><s:a href="%{getText('urlIdiomaEN')}">English</s:a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h2><s:property value="%{getText('login.title')}" /></h2>

    <s:if test="errors.size() > 0">
        <div id="lista-errores">
            <label><s:property value="%{getText('login.errors')}" />:</label>
            <s:fielderror />
            <s:actionerror/>
        </div>
    </s:if>

    <s:form action="login" method="post">
        <s:textfield name="username" id="username" label="%{getText('login.username')}" maxLength="30" />
        <s:password name="password" id="password" label="%{getText('login.password')}" maxLength="30" />
        <s:submit key="login.button_title" align="center" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is it seems not to interpret none of struts tags. It gives me plain html:

[image: struts 2 no tags working]

Any file content just ask for it. Thanks!

Comment: In the normal login flow you should implement authentication interceptor or provide jee authentication.

Comment: @RomanC This is just a practice exercise, i need to make it using sessions.

Comment: @RomanC please make the favor and read well my question.. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Did you modify the struts-config.xml file in any way?

Comment: @MichaelFreake no, struts-config.xml was not touched.

Comment: By *plain html* you mean that `getText` isn't working? Have you defined resource bundles?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes, resources are defined in a file called "package.properties" if my memory doesn't fails.

The problem is not there, when i submit the form you see in the capture above, it all renders correctly.

It doesn't work any JSP tag, even the tag that imports the stylesheet.

Comment: Not sure what isn't working... In your screenshot the only things are missing are the values for keys.

Comment: @AleksandrM also the stylesheet isn't working.

Comment: So check the dev tool network tab to see why your css isn't being loaded.